# temporary ssh access on all ec2 boxes

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I would like to offer a weekend on-call contractor ssh access with sudo on a cluster of production ec2 (ubuntu) boxes.  I would like to easily enable/disable access to all the boxes with a simple command line script or tool.

I would preferably not like to share pem files or anything like that.  How does one typically do something like this in a professional setting?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for not having ubuntu, but most linux's already have this, theres a PAM module configured with /etc/security/time.conf, the following entry in time.conf will only allow `someguy` weekend access

```
login & ssh;*;someguy;Wk0000-2400
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways to do such a thing, depending in the existing infrastructure, the amount of machines involved and the available time to setup a re-usable solution.

1. You have a centralized authentication and authorization server, tipically, an LDAP/Kerberos server, like [FreeIPA](http://www.freeipa.org). There are [clients](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=freeipa&searchon=names) for both the 2.x and the 3.x in Ubuntu as of now. In this case, you only need to enable/disable the (preferably nominal) account before and after the temporary window. Because the FreeIPA server has a CLI, this tasks is just one command. Other advantages of this approach include easily enable/disable custom HBAC and sudorules, so this solution can be applied without problems to any amount of machines and is completely reusable. There's also some puppet modules for FreeIPA in the works.
2. You don't have a centralized identity server, but have a configuration management of some sort, e.g. [`puppet`](https://puppetlabs.com). You'd only need to change one parameter in your user definition and apply the changes. This type of solution is tied to the way you promote code using your configuration management tool of choice.
3. You don't have any of those. There's still hope. Tools like [ansible](http://www.ansibleworks.com), don't require any software in the target servers, just `ssh` access. Creating and destroying an user account can be done with little effort and just a one-liner. There's a [module](http://www.ansibleworks.com/docs/released/1.1/modules.html#user) just for that.
4. You don't want to tinker with any of these. Use [`mussh`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mussh/) or a custom shell script to do the job.